# When I run ffmpeg Im getting "output file #0 does not contain any stream"

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, ffserver

Im trying to feed live stream from ffmpeg to ffserver but Im getting this error

```
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1606657336.654899, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1680x1050, 25 fps, 24.92 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Output #0, alsa, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed.ffm':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

here is my cli

```
ffmpeg -probesize 1000M -framerate 25 -video_size 1680x1050 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa -c:a aac -vf format=yuv420p http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

I'v looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903639/why-getting-and-how-to-fix-the-warning-error-on-ffmpeg-not-enough-frames-to-es) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64490002/solved-ffmpeg-consider-increasing-probesize-error-but-it-is-never-satisfied) but it did not helped

How can I fix

`Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

**EDIT:**

```
ffmpeg -probesize 1000M -framerate 25 -video_size 1680x1050 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa -i default -c:a aac -vf format=yuv420p http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers

Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1606679309.355016, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1680x1050, 25 fps, 24.92 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, alsa, from 'default':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1606679310.190079, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg1video (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (rawvideo (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[x11grab @ 0x561e2391da00] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[mpeg1video @ 0x561e23968400] bitrate tolerance 21333 too small for bitrate 64000, overriding
[mpeg1video @ 0x561e23968400] MPEG-1/2 does not support 3/1 fps
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[alsa @ 0x561e23926c40] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: I've never used the now dead ffserver, but you added `-f alsa`, but never gave it an input (such as `-f alsa -i default`). So ffmpeg is assuming you are trying to output to alsa as shown in `Output #0, alsa, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed.ffm':`.

Comment: tnx @llogan I added `-i default` but I got another error I updated question please take a look

Comment: The command doesn't match the console output.

Comment: I re-posted log but removed some parts because because "it contain" to match code, can you take a look again

Comment: @llogan here is whole log https://pastebin.com/w4NLLhid